# Lookup fields in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, lookup

Entity Application has a look up to Contact. Now, Entity Application Document has a look up to Application. In my Application Document form, I want to display the Contact who is associated with the Application Document. I do not want to be creating a look up to *Contact* as it is just bad database design.

How can I show the related contact in the Application Document form. It is after all a look up - alright, a two level look up right? I can go from the Application Document to the Application to which it is related and from there to the *Contact*.

My suggested solution would be to have a read only text field in the Application Document entity. Populate it with *Contact* (Primary Field) `onloadform` with a JavaScript.

Comment: What is *Application Document*. I'm not clear on the question, to be frank. Are you trying to refer to a field on a form of a look up entity of an other lookup entity?

Comment: Yes, on the form of Application Document alongside Application (a lookup), I want to display the Contact (which is a lookup on Application).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd resolve it as a call to the DB, fetching the linked entity and then fetch it's linked entity. JavaScript seems to be the wises choice in this case.

However, you mention that you find this solution bad, so I might be missing a requirement.

Comment: No, I said it is a bad solution because I thought of the solution and as I am just about learning CRM 2011 there may be better solutions.

Comment: @Kanini There **might** be but that's the one I'd deploy until some issues cause me to rethink. +1 for a timid and humble attitude towards CRM. I recognize myself there. If you're satisfied, accept the reply as the answer. If not, please explain what's missing.